# ExceptionFilter equivalent of try catch with WebException details

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a very basic global error filter:

```
public class HandleMyErrorAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception raisedException = context.Exception;
        LogHelper.LogException(raisedException);
    }
}
```

And this handles my app's errors very well. However, in specific instances, I want to capture more details from the exception. Specifically, I want more details if the exception is a `WebException` (instead of a generic `Exception`). To handle this, I have some try-catch blocks in various places throughout my code. For example:

```
        //...
        //...Request object is created here
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            this.data = jss.Deserialize<RingCentralAuthenticatedModel>(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            //I use this to capture more detailed info (headers, etc) if I get a WebException
            var msg = ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            msg += "Url: " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + request.RequestUri + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            msg += "Request:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (var key in request.Headers.AllKeys)
                msg += key + " = " + request.Headers[key] + Environment.NewLine;
            msg += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            msg += "Response:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (var key in ex.Response.Headers.AllKeys)
                msg += key + " = " + ex.Response.Headers[key] + Environment.NewLine;
            //I then pass this more detailed info on to the generic error filter to be logged
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle this within the `HandleMyErrorAttribute` class **alone** (without using the try-catch blocks). My thought is to detect whether the raised exception within my filter is a `WebException`, and if it is, then pull out that detailed info for the logs. What is the equivalent of my try-catch block handled by the `HandleMyErrorAttribute` instead?

Comment: Can you just try to cast the Exception to a WebException using 'as WebException.'  If it's null then you don't have a WebException.  if it isn't log your extra stuff.

Comment: That's a good thought, @Fran. I'm investigating it.